# Jline Terminal Writer Outputting Wrong Formatted Output

Tags: java, jline

We're having some issues with the Jline library terminal when trying to use it's writer. When we try to write a string using the terminal writer's print statement, it's appending characters around the string.

Example:
When printing: `terminal.writer().print("Username:");` 
We get the output string as "�[?1l�>�[?1000l�[?2004lUsername:�[?1h�=�[?2004h", where as we want to get only "Username:" as the output.

We've tried the solution from this link https://github.com/jline/jline3/issues/181 by setting the "BRACKETED_PASTE_OFF". But that didn't work.

Comment: maybe it would help to see the code, at least how `terminal` comes to live. the codes resemble ANSI escape codes, try setting `jansi` to `false`. (e.g. `...2004...` is BRACKETED_PASTE mode command)

Comment: So setting jansi to false in the terminal builder didn't work. However setting the option (BRACKETED_PASTE, false) on the linereader did get rid of the 2004 strings. But I'm still getting some more stuff attached to the user name field "[?1l>[?1000lUsername:[?1h=". Looking if any other option needs to be disabled/ enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, I had to use printAbove to remove the string appended when reading a line and set the BRACKETED_PASTE as false to remove the brackets appended during the cleanup phase:

`final TerminalBuilder builder = TerminalBuilder.builder(); builder.jansi(false); 
builder.streams(in, out); 
terminal = builder.build();
reader = LineReaderBuilder.builder().terminal(terminal).build(); reader.option(BRACKETED_PASTE, false);
reader.printAbove(StringToPrint);
terminal.writer().print(StringToPrint);`